# Attaching an existing database with MySQL

Tags: mysql

Disclaimer: I have never used MySQL before!

I have a folder containing a number of .frm, .myd and .myi files that I believe are a MySQL database. I have pulled these files from a defunct server for a client who has not used the server or database for some years but is now looking to resurect some of the data for a new venture.

I have downloaded the latest free edition of MySQL, along with MySQL Workbench and am looking to connecct the existing database to the new installation; the equivalent to an "Attach" if I were using MS SQL Server.

I have found a few articles that say if I simply copy the folder into the data folder for MySQL and restart the service the database will show up. I have tried this (using both the data folder within the installation folder and also the "MySQL Datafiles" folder created during the intial configuration but when I restart the service nothing shows up.

How should I go about attaching this database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. I found the answer, the folder I was adding the database to was the wrong one.
Though I had found 2 "data" folders, there was a 3rd hiding in C:\ApplicationData; once I added my data files in here and restarted the MySQL service I could see the data.

Comment: You did not answer the question: *"How should I go about attaching this database?"* Please show the command to attach to a database in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 8 the default folder where MySql databases are stored is:

> C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data

5.6 is the version.

Please note it is **ProgramData** not **Program Files** which is easy to overlook.

Copying there and restarting the service worked fine for me. I'm even copying the DBs from an earlier 5.X version.

Comment: You did not answer the question: *"How should I go about attaching this database?"* Please show the command to attach to a database in MySQL.