# How to attach mysql database file

Tags: mysql

I have installed mysql and mysqlworkbench 5.2 CE, i want to attach mysql database file.
I was trying to attach it with phpmyadmin but the database file is too large.
Can anyone tell me how to attach or provide the link for this answer,...thanks

Comment: Do attach means restore then please follow http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/  otherwise http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789234/attaching-an-existing-database-with-mysql

Comment: If its a sql file you could do `mysql -u [user] -p -h [host] [dbname] < [database_file.sql]` from command line.  Replace the variables accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use command line client. In the simplest form:

```
mysql -h [hostname] -u [username] -p [dbname] < [db_file_name.sql]
```

To get more information about command usage, just type in:

```
mysql --help
```