# Would installing WAMP delete your current local databases?

Tags: database, wamp, local

I recently followed a tutorial on getting started with WordPress which included installing a WAMP Server.

Some days later I checked on a Java program that I'm working on which connects to a local database, but it could no longer connect to that database, and if i checked in the MySQL WorkBench or DataGrip it seemed as in that database did not exsist anymore, and it only showed my database from my WordPress project, all the other local databases i had made before installing WAMP are gone.

Is there any way to find them?

**EDIT:** They DO exist in the folder C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data but I don't know how to access them, as they're not working in my Java program, or not showing in the WorkBench as schemas anymore

Comment: Your databases will have become detached when you installed MySQL server again, if you see the following resource on how to restore a db to mysql:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369869/how-to-attach-mysql-database-file - If you restore each db then they will be available to view in phpmyadmin / workbench again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You now have 2 MYSQL Servers installed and therefore which ever one is started first will be the one that `phpMyAdmin` or `Workbench` talks to.

To get to your old database, just stop the wampserver MySQL server

```
[left click] wampmanager -> MYSQL-> Service Administrator->Stop Service
```

Then go into the services snapin

```
Windows Key+R
Enter services.msc
Press the OK button
```

Find the service called `MYSQL` and start that.

You should now be able to access the old database using `phpMyAdmin` or `WorkBench`

Backup the old database

Then from the services snapin agian STOP the MYSQL service.

Restart the WAMPServer MySQL

```
[left click] wampmanager -> MYSQL-> Service Administrator->Start Service
```

Now restore your database into the WAMPServer version of MySQL.

Once this is completed, you can uninstall the old MySQL Server instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the new Wamp in a new folder and lost access to your databases, this will help you:

In order to restore access your previous WAMP services and databases you can re-run your previous `wampmanager.exe` that is found on the old version `Wamp` folder, right click Wamp icon from icons tray `Tools` > `Reinstall all services`.

[image]

This will be enough to export a dump from your databases, then you will be able to import them to the MySQL that belongs to the new `Wamp` version installed