# Moving wordpress from xampp to xampp

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, xampp, hard-drive

I'm not a programer I just play around html and css. Few weeks ago I was asked to make a Wordpress site for a friend. Thinking that the best idea would be to do it on XAMPP and then move it to live, I worked on it for quite some time.

Just when I was about to finish, something happened with powersurge and my computer got totaled, motherboard, graphics, power, all fried, all except for hard disc that somehow survived.

Now I got a laptop and new XAMPP instalation, but I have no idea how to transfer site from my old Hard disc to new. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

- Edit: I have moved files from old xampp folder to new, but problem is database.

Comment: Is this a hardware question, or have you already recovered the contents of the old drive?

Comment: Hooking up an old hard drive to a different computer is really easy with a SATA to USB adapter kit or just buy an all-in-one docking station. Anyways, this question is incredibly off-topic here and might even be off-topic at SuperUser but idk.

Comment: Moved files, no problems there, but it's wordpress so moving it to new htdocs is just a part, problem is Mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

Usually(default) xampp is installed on the C drive, you can find it at:

`C:\xampp\`

projects are stored in the `htdocs` file inside of that, move the project(or projects if you have multiple) in its entirety from the old htdocs file to the new one.

Comment: I moved files to new htdocs, but I don't know how to move Mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

> Get your MySQL Data Files from `C:\XAMPP\mysql\data` and follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13789234/6294600)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following this steps:

1) copy your site from c:/xampp/htdocs/[copy your site name folder]
(before just check that your xampp install in which drive. common is C drive).

2)export database from phpmyadmin
type in URL : http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
then select your database and export it.

3)paste your folder in new PC's xampp/htdocs

4)import your database in your new Xampp.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way and its working good.

1. Install xammp and wordpress on new computer.
2. copy wordpress folder from C:\xampp\apps folder
3. Export wordpress folder from phpmyadmin.
4. replace the wordpress folder to new system and drop all table from wordpress db and 
   import the old db datas.
   Notes:

   1. If you config or merge other tools like phpbb means you have to change that also to 
      the new location.